# JS find id in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have web chat and lot of users, i have done opening chatting windows like this

```
chatbox.newWindow(name, $(this).find("span").data("id"));
```

and picking them up from friends online list, but i want to get the ID of the each chat, when i hit send message

for example i want to get the id of the chat of Nice guy when i hit send message
is there any way to get closest id of span ?

html :

```
<div id="friends_panel">
            <span>Online uživatelé</span>
            <div class="user">
                <span data-id="1">Nice guy</span>
            </div>
            <div class="user">
                <span data-id="2">John</span>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: What's wrong with the sample you've already posted?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.?

Comment: where is your send button  ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can solve this by using .closest().

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself - each.

```
$(this).find("span[data-id]").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('id'))
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F5hyz/1/

If I understood your correctly and you're opening multiple chat windows with user name and id - it could be something like:

```
$(this).find("span[data-id]").each(function() {
    chatbox.newWindow($(this).text(), $(this).data('id'));
})
```

If among all the spans that have "data-id" you're looking specifically for "Nice guy" - you can filer him out:

```
var id = $(this).find("span[data-id]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Nice guy';
}).data('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it your query gets both of the `<span>`s, and thus can't return the `date-id` property. iterate over the `<span>`s and see what you get.